# How can I get the exact post time of a comment I made?

Tags: imgur

I made a comment on an Imgur post. A friend told me "haha I saw that comment! That was on Reddit, right?" No, no my friend. It was on Imgur. Now I have to know when, to the second, I made my comment. I know when the Reddit comment was made because the alt-text on dates is the UTC time the [whatever element the date represents] was posted. But on Imgur, I can't find this information.

But this is 2014. There has to be a way. Right? RIGHT?! Please help me find the exact time an Imgur comment is posted!

Comment: Have you done a "view source" on the page to see if they include the actual post time in comments?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but not an easy one. Use the [/comment method of Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/models/comment), which returns, among other things, the epoch timestamp of the comment (i.e., with accuracy up to 1 second).

The path is https://api.imgur.com/3/comment/{id} where {id} is the number at the end of the permalink of a comment. The data returned by the API looks like the example below, where `datetime` is the field you want. A tool such as http://www.epochconverter.com/ can convert it to human-readable form.

The only catch is: Imgur API requires authorization, so before using it, you will need to jump through the registration hoops described at https://api.imgur.com/

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1110,
        "image_id": "K84kO",
        "caption": "This is a Test Caption sent via the API!",
        "author": "joshTest",
        "author_id": 384077,
        "on_album":false,
        "album_cover":null,
        "ups": 5,
        "downs": 0,
        "points": 5,
        "datetime": 1346977487,
        "parent_id": null,
        "deleted": true
    },
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}
```